SSH Access Denied Even After Configuring AllowUsers with IPv4 Addresses
I am trying to restrict SSH access on my VPS to specific users and IP addresses by using the AllowUsers directive in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. I added the following configuration:
AllowUsers user1@192.168.1.100 user2@192.168.1.101

However, when the specified users try to log in from their respective IP addresses, they receive the following error:
Permission denied (publickey)

I've Tried :

Checking IP address accuracy: Confirmed that the IP addresses
provided in the AllowUsers directive are correct.
Verifying SSH keys: Ensured that the SSH keys are properly set up and that the users can authenticate using their keys.
Reviewing sshd_config: Looked through the entire sshd_config file for any conflicting settings that might override the AllowUsers directive.
Restarting SSH service: Restarted the SSH service after each change to ensure that the configuration updates are applied.

I would like to configure the AllowUsers directive to permit access only to specific users from designated IP addresses. How can I achieve this without running into the "Permission denied (publickey)" error?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Post the entire configuration file, verbose logs from both client and server, without this information your question cannot be answered
